# vCenter network setup

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Following design to be applied:

- ESXi Host standalone
- vCenter deployed on ESXi

**Network-Config ESXi:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Config vCenter:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Error-Message:**
[image]
[image]

**Problem:**
I want to have the vCenter management enabled on the internal net 10.10.10.200, so that I can later deploy a Zscaler app-connector and make the vCenter available via Zscaler.
Unfortunately I can neither add the port group "internal MGMT Net" to the vCenter VM, nor can I set the vCenter IP-Configuration.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

**Network Plan***
[image]

Comment: Make a little drawing showing how you want the networking to be, including vlan id's and IP ranges please. Help us to understand your requirement.

Comment: Hi @Chopper3,
thanks, I have added this

Comment: Oh I see - so what's doing the routing? ESXi's vSwitch is just a switch, it doesn't route.

Comment: Hi @Chopper3, 
well, the main problem is, that I can not assign the portgroups to the VMs.
In the dropdown-menu from the networkinterfaces for the VMs, the portgroups just dont appear.

Comment: Oh, that's odd, is this via the Host Web Client on the host or via vCenter?